# Can a random string be used as unique UserAgent?

Tags: java, jsoup, user-agent

I am logging into a portal on behalf of a user using JSoup which works fine, now the problem is I want to log into this portal of behalf of multiple users at the same time(thousands or unlimited would be perfect).

I know that unique sessions are associated with each UserAgent but the problem is there are only handful of UserAgents, can a random/unique string achieve logging into same portal on behalf on multiple users simultaneously?

Comment: User agent identifies the browser, not the user.

Comment: Each browser keeps its own cookies so indirectly it is somewhat the same thing, I guess

Comment: What's the same as what? The user agent has nothing to do with cookies, session, or user.

Comment: I mean you can log into facebook using multiple accounts at the same time with different browser, what am I missing here.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the user agent and everything to do with the cookie jar.

Comment: got it, so can I store cookies associated with each user and the re-use these cookies some time later before its expiration time to achieve my goal this way?

Comment: You're missing what cookies and user agents are. *All* the user agent is is a string that (is supposed to) identify the client you're using. Name, renderer, sometimes OS, etc. of the browser. That's all. Nothing else. Cookies are (somewhat) persistent storage of URL-based information like the session ID. The session id is generally what's important in identifying a unique ... well, session.

Comment: The purpose of the user agent string is to identify the browser's type (Chrome, FF, some mobile browser) and not a specific browser of a specific user. The reason is that some browsers have features that others don't have, so they need to get different responses (like HTML files) from the servers. Also, you would want to know if the user accesses your server from mobile device or a PC, and send him different pages with different sizes (the mobile screen is smaller than PC's screen).